# Fit Two-Term Exponential Model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, exponential

I found how to fit a Two-Term Exponential Model in Matlab with the fit function:

```
f2 = fit(x,y,'exp2')
f2(x) = a*exp(b*x) + c*exp(d*x)
```

However, I don't want to use this standard model. My exponential model is:

```
f2(x) = a*exp(b*x) + (1-a)*exp(c*x)
```

Can someone please help me how to fit this model?

Greetings from Holland,
Inge

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

```
f = fit(x,y,fittype('a*exp(b*x)+(1-a)*exp(c*x)','coeff',{'a','b','c'}))
```

what you want? (using matlab command 'help fittype')

Comment: I can't get it to work. I think I miss something. I get this error message:

    Error using fit>iFit (line 340)
    Inf computed by model function, fitting cannot continue.
    Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I used the lsqcurvefit for non-linear curve fitting Maybe for some people interested, here is the code I used:

```
F = @(x,xdata)S0*((1-x(1))*exp(-1*xdata*x(2)) + x(1)*exp(-1*xdata*x(3)));
x0 = [0 0 0 ]    
[x] = lsqcurvefit(F,x0,xdatapoints,y);
```